# unable to create notification_key for gcm using node js

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, google-cloud-messaging

I am getting 404 error when I try to create notification_key in gcm using node.js. My code is

```
var request = require('request');

request.post({
uri: 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification',

request:
{ 
"operation": "create",
"notification_key_name": "appUser-Chris",
"notification_key": "aUniqueKey",
"registration_ids": ['**', '****']
},

headers: {
'content-type': "application/json",
'project_id' : 'fluid-booking-638',
'Authorization' : 'key=*****'
}


}, function(err, response, body) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(response);
    console.log(body);
});
```

Where am I doing mistake ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are wrong here :

> 'project_id' : 'fluid-booking-638',

Use the project number (the 12 digits number your app uses in order to register to GCM.

I know that the docs say

> Header : "project_id":

But the docs have been known to mix the terms `projectID` and `projectNumber` before. In fact, originally the 12 digits number used to be called the project ID.

Comment: Hi, Thanks it worked to some extent. But now gcm says me "BadJsonFormat". All json's seem to correct. Am I missing something?

Comment: @chanakya try to put the reg ids in double quotes

Comment: It should not be request tag over there, it should be 'json' tag.
Thanks @Eran.